# Mongodb - multi-stages query - calculate, compare and return results

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have mongodb documents as follows:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5e839a223552e431fxd3c979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:41.259Z',
    regionId: 'eg',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 30,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_a'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '5e839a223559e431fxd3c979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:42.259Z',
    regionId: 'eg',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 10,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_b'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '5e839a223552ed82fxd3c979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:43.259Z',
    regionId: 'eg',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 15,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_a'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '5e8902223552e431fxd3c979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:44.259Z',
    regionId: 'eg',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 55,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_a'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '5e839a223552e43jjid3c979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:45.259Z',
    regionId: 'eg',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 7,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_b'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '5e839a223552e431fx0c3979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:46.259Z',
    regionId: 'eg',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 120,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_c'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: '5e839a22ggt2e431fxd3c979',
    dateTime: '2020-03-31T19:29:47.259Z',
    regionId: 'us',
    transId: 'serviceFee',
    revenue: 500,
    details: {
      serviceId: 'serv_a'
    }
  },
]
```

looking to the documents we can say:

- there are two regions, as per `regionId`: `[eg,us]`,
- there are three services, as per `serviceId`: `[serv_a, serv_b, serv_c]`,
- each document shows the revenue of a particular service in a particular region.

now here is what I want:

- I want to know the best performing service (with highest total revenue) in a particular region (ex. eg).
- I also want to know the worst performing service in the same region.
- So expected result should be:

  - Best performing service in region `'eg'` is: `serv_c`
  - Worst performing service in the region is: `serv_b`

So from my basic understanding, I think I need to find a way to calculate the total revenues of each service in the region (ex. eg) and then compare between the totals to decide which is the highest and which is the lowest! I think I should use mongodb `aggregate` function, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: You can use the aggregation stage `$group` , and the aggregation operators like `$sum`, `$max` and `$min`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.
Here is an example in javascript showing how did I do it:

```
var bestPerformingService = 'ph_besterviceId'; // <-- value placeholder
var worstPerformingService = 'ph_worstServiceId' // <-- value placeholder
var trId = 'serviceFee'; // <-- selected transId
var regId = 'eg'; // <-- selected regionId
var resultArray = await records_revenues_model.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         regionId: regId,
         transId: trId,
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: '$details.serviceId',
         totalRevenues: { $sum: '$revenue' },
      }
   },
   {
      $sort: { totalRevenues: -1 }
   },
]).exec() || [];

try {
   bestPerformingService = resultArray[0]._id;
   worstPerformingService = resultArray[resultArray.length - 1]._id;
} catch (error) {
   methods.log(`safed error : ${error}`);
}

console.log(`best performing service: ${bestPerformingService}`);
console.log(`worst performing service: ${worstPerformingService}`);

// expected outcome:
// best performing service: serv_c
// worst performing service: serv_b
```

I hope this can be useful to someone someday.